# podman: environment variables in CMD

Tags: podman

I'd like to pass a variable to podman's `CMD` when starting the container.  However, the variable ends up undefined.

Minimal image:

```
FROM alpine:latest
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo", "$VAR"]
```

Running this minimal image with

```sh
podman run -e VAR=0 minimal-image
```

only returns an empty string and not the expected 0.  From within the container `VAR` holds the value of 0 as I would expect.

```sh
podman run -it -e VAR=0 minimal-image sh
# inside container:
echo $VAR
0
```

Comment: VAR is only defined in the container.  you have done nothing to define VAR in the shell instance that you launched podman container from.   you told podman to set the variable in the container but that goes away when the container process exits.

Comment: As the CMD line from the containerfile is executed *inside* the container how is this related to the question?

Comment: was going on memory on the answer, you are correct, it is run with the container.

Comment: i was thinking of RUN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument after "-c" should contain the full command.

In other words, replace

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo", "$VAR"]
```

with

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo $VAR"]
```

Demo:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine:latest
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo $VAR"]
$ podman build -q -t test .
4a09e7eb28f0e40cd903cbf653b71a1265fce67e07f9cba5ab6f38719fe27a03
$ podman run -e VAR=0 localhost/test
0
$
```

Comment: that does not seem to match the question that was asked.  Of course it could be the person asking did not properly explain what they were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't use "ENV" within your Containerfile, the variable $VAR doesn't actually exist inside your container.

```
FROM alpine:latest
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo", "$VAR"]
```

Your Containerfile should look like this.

```
FROM alpine:latest
ARG value=Hello
ENV VAR=$value
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo", "$VAR"]
```

You can also add ARG to control the variable during the build time.

```
podman build --build-arg value="new_value" -t hello .
podman run -e VAR="new_value2" localhost/hello
```

Comment: It is not true that variables are only visible if declared in the containerfile.  Besides that there is already an accepted answer that is correct.